# Share a single or multiple list item with users

Tags: list, item, share

I am new to SharePoint and would like to ask a question regarding lists.

I created a list with several items. How is it possible to share this single item with another user?

Should this user be in a group to be able to share it with them?

I tried to click on the item itself and then went to "Items" and then "Shared with" --> Advanced --> Stop inheriting permissions --> Grant Permissions --> Enter the email address of the person.

I would like the user to be able to just edit the list item and have access to only that list item and not be able to see other items.

I work in a company and they use SharePoint site for my department however I am not one of the owners of this site. Would that be a problem?

Thanks you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can broke the permissions at list level and then grant permissions at item level. This way user will be able to just edit that list item and have access to only that list item and not be able to see other items.

Answer (score 0):

When sharing just one item with a user make sure that the feature "Limited-access user permission lockdown mode" located at http://YourIntranet.com/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx?Scope=Site is deactivated. Otherwise the user will not be able to edit or even access the item/site.

> I tried to click on the item itself and then went to "Items" and then "Shared with" --> Advanced --> Stop inheriting permissions --> Grant Permissions --> Enter the email address of the person.

This will work assuming you have the right to assign permissions. if not check with the admin of the site or your tech support guys for assistance .